# NextJS - when I make a change in my project's file, a strange "cache/typescript/2.9/node_modules/@types/react'" appear on my imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

All is in the title. I'm working in NextJS. When I make a change in the organization of my project's file, a strange message

> ".cache/typescript/2.9/node_modules/@types/react'"

appears on my imports, specifically my Reactjs's imports. I have tried to retrace the problem by Googling but I have found nothing helpful. Does anyone know what that means? Any hint would be great.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your error is. Is it on build logs, in the code directly or somewhere else?

Comment: hi that was a fail with some version of VSCode, after update to the last version it work well it seems, thanks at least

Comment: You should answer your own question and validate the answer then ^^ That way this can help someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was simply a fail with some version of VSCode, after having realized an update to the latest version it works well now.